# PDF Sharp and MigraDocs Image Issue in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdfsharp, migradoc, .net-core-2.2

I have an issue with PDF Sharp and Migra Docs implementation in .NET Core.

I am using all the .net core dlls for it i.e.

MigraDoc.Rendering.Core,
PdfSharpCore, 
PdfSharp.Charting.Core, 
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Core

The PDF is being generated fine.

The images are not being attached. I read on few articles here but it doesn't really help.

The error i am getting is not about System.Drawing issue as the other articles suggests.

The following error message shows up for all the images in the document.

System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dicitionary 2 localResourceSets, Boolean .. )

I have tried to look for this particular error and tried to add resource files but that didn't help.

The code works perfectly fine for .NET frameworks (Any). It's just not working with .NET Core DLLS.

```
        Section sec = document.AddSection();

        Image image = new Image();

        image = sec.AddImage(Tools.GetMainPageHeader());

        image.Width = "190mm";
        image.Height = "50mm";
        image.Left = ShapePosition.Center;
```

The above code when executed on .NET core defines the dimensions of the image with the allocated width and height but instead of attaching the image, the error message is displayed.

Comment: I assume you are using a port of MigraDoc. Which one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, no idea about the port. Like i mentioned ealier, i am using the following nuget packages. 
MigraDoc.Rendering.Core,
PdfSharpCore,    PdfSharp.Charting.Core, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Core

Comment: So you are using an inofficial port of PDFsharp and MigraDoc that was published 9 months ago. I don't know what `Grovel` is, but maybe a Grovel expert or a person familiar with that specific port can help you. Image handling within this port is different from the standard implementation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Instead of MigraDoc.Rendering.Core, use MigraDocCore.Rendering;

Correct Package:
Install-Package MigraDocCore.Rendering

Wrong Package:
Install-Package MigraDoc.Rendering.Core